# spresenseの開発用のページが見れなくなっているのですが、どこかに移動してしまったんでしょうか？

Tags: spresense, arduino

developer.sony.comには接続はできるのですが、spresenseの開発ページだけ「page not found」と表示されます。ネットワークやデバイスを変えてみても見れませんでした。
もしページを見る方法があれば教えて欲しいです。

Comment: https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/sdk_set_up_ja.html とか、ウチからなら見えますが...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントの通り、Developer Worldの[Home](https://developer.sony.com/ja/spresense/development-guides/home_ja.html)からのリンクで各種開発ページを閲覧できます。

今回のご質問は、Googleなどの検索エンジンで下記のようなURLがヒットして「page not found」になることに起因していると予想されます。
https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/introduction/

ちなみに上記のURLを下記のURLに直接書き換えると目的のページに遷移できます。
`/developer-tools/` → `/development-guides/`
`introduction/` → `introduction_ja.html`

ただしページ構成が変わっていて、単純なURL書き換えでは遷移できないURLの方が多いようです。